# Nth Child using Jquery instead of CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using `nth-child` in my css code, but it does not work in IE 8.
I know IE 8 can't handle `nth-child` but I need to find a way to make it work.

Here's my code :

```
.paypalshop .shop-groups li:nth-child(1){
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width:200px;

   }

.paypalshop .shop-groups li:nth-child(2){
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width:150px;
   }

.paypalshop .shop-groups li:nth-child(3){
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width:210px;
   }

.paypalshop .shop-groups li:nth-child(4){
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width:200px;
   }

.paypalshop .shop-groups li:nth-child(5){
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width:70px;
   }

.paypalshop .shop-groups li:nth-child(6){
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width:105px;
   }

.paypalshop .shop-groups li:nth-child(7){
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width:154px;
   }

.paypalshop .shop-groups li:nth-child(8){
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width:130px;
   }   

.paypalshop .shop-groups li:nth-child(9){
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width:220px;
   }
.paypalshop .shop-groups li:nth-child(10){
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width:220px;
   }
```

So what I need is to find a way to make the `nth-child` function work on IE 8. Is there any jQuery method I could use to make it work on IE 8?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes use the :nth-child selector

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

with the css change

http://api.jquery.com/css/

e.g.

```
$("paypalshop .shop-groups li:nth-child(2)").css("width":"150px","float":"left","border":"1px solid #ccc");
```

Comment: This would bypass IE incompatibility?

Comment: I believe so as EI8 can handle CSS and the selection is done via jQuery accessing the DOM. I don't have IE8 to test on but I think it should work.

Comment: I will test it and will get back to you! Thanks

Comment: Brilliant. I'm pretty sure this would work for other pseudo-elements too!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of altering CSS with jQuery (adding 80kb to your page load and javascript dependency on the layout of your website), why don't you add classes to each of those `li`'s?

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="normal"><!-- 200px --></li>
    <li class="narrow"><!--- 70px --></li>
    <li class="wide"><!-- 220px --></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li { float: left; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
li.normal { width: 200px; }
li.narrow { width: 70px; }
li.wide { width: 220px; }
```

Imo, this is a cleaner, more readable solution that is easier to maintain and solves your problem for each and every browser imagineably in use today.